# Shopware: How to add new field to existing third party plugin

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, shopware

I want to extend an existing third party plugin via another plugin and add a new field in backend (checkbox). I could not find the answer how to extend the tables of another plugin.

I tried the 'shopware_attribute.crud_service' but it didn't work, I got the information that "Provided table is no attribute table".
I followed the example from https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-extension-by-plugin/
But in those examples the new option type uses the same column and does not extend the database with a new field

Shopware 5.5.10

Answer (score 1):

I'd really like to give you a helpful answer but its just a mess to do this.

It is possible by adding the tables to the attributes.
You have to generate the attribute models for a specific table like `$this->container->get('models')->generateAttributeModels(['my_custom_table_one','my_custom_table_two']);`

In addition to that you have to overwrite the `Shopware\Bundle\AttributeBundle\Service\TableMapping`.
For what you should create an action that defines your tables, with a model, identifiers, keys and so on, create a custom AttributeLoaderService for getting all attributes.

The best thing you can do is looking inside shopware to get all needed locations and classes for creating attributes.

Also you need to overwrite the extjs of the other plugin and load the attribute tables inside the views.
I would start with tables that my plugin created to be in a clear start.